# How can create a bpel project on Eclipse (I am using 2023-3)

Tags: eclipse, wso2, bpel

I am trying to start with bpel on Eclipse, so I installed WSO2 Developer Studio. But it is not working to recognize a .bpel file. On my facet's project I got "Implementation of project facet bpel.facet.core could not be found. Functionality will be limited"

An in Error log I have next traces:

```
*eclipse.buildId=4.27.0.20230309-1200
java.version=18.0.2.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/Users/lm2a/TRAINING-IT/SOA-BPEL/workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
This is a continuation of log file /Users/lm2a/TRAINING-IT/SOA-BPEL/workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2023-04-11 12:38:07.326
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core
Error
Tue Apr 11 12:42:24 CEST 2023
Failed while invoking preset factory "org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core".
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.iterator()" because "facets" is null
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.BasicJpaEEConfigurationPresetFactory.findProjectFacetVersion(BasicJpaEEConfigurationPresetFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.facet.BasicJpaEEConfigurationPresetFactory.createPreset(BasicJpaEEConfigurationPresetFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.PresetsExtensionPoint$DynamicPreset.resolve(PresetsExtensionPoint.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.refreshAvailablePresets(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.setProjectFacets(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.clone(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2123)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:1999)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$4.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$5.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)*
```

**Any help will be very welcomed.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Vanilla Eclipse? If so Download the `Integration Studio` from [here](https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/releases/tag/v8.1.0). Then Go to Help -> Getting Started and then you should be able to create a BPMN project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ycr! It looks very interesting. I downloaded and installed the .dmg file for Mac and tried to open it, but on Mac Ventura 13.1 it quits unexpectedly. Is there any other installation step or requirement that I could have omitted?

Comment: @lm2a I don't think so, what errors do you see in eclipse logs?

Comment: Mac error log show a very long error details. Here you have the main lines explaining the error: Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [8584]